# Install two different CMS in same directory

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, installation, opencart

I have a wordpress website (http://www.pkbazaar.pk). But now I want to install opencart as main website, and don't want to delete wordpress and don't want to move wordpress in sub-directory.

Can I install wordpress and OpenCart in same directory and run both opencart and wordpress parallel.

Comment: No you can't run 2 index files in same directory. Wether you can run wordpress or open cart at a time.

Comment: What are you actually expecting to happen when someone visits the main page of your website?